# Can't compare a cell to a column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to compare a column to a cell in excel several times.
The columns are copy pasted from a PDF (only way to get the information). The results are bad, with trailing spaces, some completely random cells inserted (eg Lines 36 and 37), etc. Fromatting is not very consistent between the columns.

I've been trying to use different formulas like Vlookup and if(match), which work when I try them on a test excel file. But they always fail on this data or give me weird/wrong results. I have tried to remove trailing spaces but this does not solve the problem.

Could someone please take a look at the file? (https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=9B56C77E51128EBF!10357)

The goal is to look at each name from column A (A2, A3, A4 ...) and see if it is present in B:B, then see if it is present in C:C, and tell me. I really only need the number of column A names that are matched in column B and C respectively.

If a few matching operations fail because of inconsistent formatting, that is fine. As there are about 670 items it's fine is there is some percentage of error. I care about the final statistical result.

Thanks!

(by the way, I am not infringing on anyone's privacy by posting this data, the PDFs it is pasted from are freely available online and are university admission results in France)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem is the non-breaking space, character 160.

You can use the following to remove the non-breaking space:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),"")
```

At least in the first few names, that is the problem I found.

`TRIM()` didn't fix the problem with matching, nor did `CLEAN()`. I pasted a few problematic cells into a text editor and viewed the codes. There were two spaces between certain names, and the symbols for the two were different. I found the character code with the following formula operating on `ABDELLI  Cyrielle`:

```
=CODE(MID(A$3,9,1))
```

The result was "160", which you can produce in Excel with `CHAR(160)`. If you use the above formula for the 8th character, it gives you 32, which is the code for the normal space.

Comment: nice, i gotta remember that one.

Comment: hi Dane, Thanks for your help.

 I made columns D, E and F, wherein I copy the contents of columns A, C and C and substitue 160 for nothing.
It still does not work. I get strange results with Match(), sometimes all names are matched, sometimes none are matched.Using exact() gives false for all names.

Comment: What's your formula? Perhaps post the formula in your question. Why doesn't `vlookup()` with a final parameter of `FALSE` work for you?

Comment: hi Dane, it worked now!